# How do I disable notifications in my personal profile for activity on pages I am an admin of?

Tags: facebook, notifications

I'm an admin of several pages on Facebook (for technical stuff like RSS imports, etc.), but neither do I contribute content nor do I care about their content.

Still, as an admin, I get notifications (upper left hand, the globe icon) about activity (someone liked this, someone posted that) on those pages in my personal (!) profile .

Does anyone have the same issue? Is there any way to explicitly disable notifications for certain pages?

(This behavior seems to be new, by the way; I'm only seeing those notifications for a few weeks now.)

Comment: I'm admin of two pages, but I only get notifications (on-site) from one. I don't know how I disabled that and I'm still trying to find out.

Comment: Go to **`Settings>Notifications> Edit(On Facebook) > Pages you manage`** and uncheck pages as you wish !

Answer (score 5):

A few things you can try:

1. Visit https://www.facebook.com/pages/edit/?id=[PAGE-ID]&sk=yoursettings Replace [PAGE-ID] with the ID of the page you're getting updates from. Make sure both of the check boxes on this page are not checked. (They are checked by default).
2. You should also visit https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=Pages&view and click the "Pages" item to expand it, then click on the "Change email settings for individual pages" and uncheck the boxes pages you don't care about.
3. On your news feed, click the down arrow in the upper right of the div containing a story from a page you don't care about and select "Hide all by [page name]".

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, points 1 and 2 relate only to e-mail notifications, not on-site notifications (and all checkboxes are already disabled anyways). Point 3 relates to the news feed, but I don't see any content from the mentioned pages there. I was referring to the globe icon in the left hand side of the top toolbar.

Comment: As far as I can see, to Facebook, there is only one notification setting that handles emails and the "globe icon" notifications. Click the Globe icon, and go to "Notification settings" and it takes me to the same dialog in my point 2 above.

Comment: Of course, YMMV. I've seen where my Facebook interface and menus are completely different than my wife's on the same PC, browser, network, etc.

Comment: Has Facebook changed again? I can’t find any settings anywhere controlling what notifications appear under the globe icon (and push to my phone!) All I can find is the email settings (which are greyed out?)

Comment: Point 1 did it for me, it had check boxes for both email and site notifications for events relating to the page.

Comment: The link from Point 2 now gives you a [Pages you manage](http://i.imgur.com/j3s4jwU.png) section that allows you to disable page notifications on your personal profile.

Answer (score 4):

The page notifications do appear under your personal-profile globe icon if you set using your page as you personally. If you return to using your page as your page, the notifications will appear only if you use the whole Facebook as your page.

Comment: I have since removed myself as admin from these pages, however, I vaguely remember such a setting somewhere. If anyone having the same problem confirms this as solution, I'll put yours down as best answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Update May 2016

In your private Facebook account click on rightmost arrow icon in blue bar on top of page and go to *Settings*. From left menu select *Notifications*. Click on the Edit button on the *On Facebook* section. If you click on Edit it will roll down a list of all pages you manage and you can toggle notifications on/off for each of them.

[image]